# Проектирование БД. Таблица "люди"

Tags: sql, база-данных

Возникла проблема при проектировании БД. У меня есть фильмы, в которых участвует множество актеров, а также режиссеры. Сначала актеров я реализовал с помощью сводной таблицы, режиссеры же были полем таблицы "**фильмы**".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решил объединить всех этих людей в таблицу "**люди**", отношение "многие-ко-многим" для актёров я оставил, режиссера (одного из людей) же связал напрямую с таблицей "**фильмы**" отношением один-ко-многим. Т.е. таблица "люди" имеет отношения "**один-ко-многим**" и "**многие-ко-многим**" с таблицей "фильмы" **одновременно**, что мне кажется неправильным.

Правильный ли это подход к реализации БД, если нет - тогда как правильно реализовать нужную связь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данную проблему следующим образом:

1. Создал дополнительную таблицу "роль"
2. Образовал связь "один-ко-многим" таблицы "роль" со сводной таблицей "фильм-актер"
3. Переделал первичный ключ в таблице "фильм-актер" на составной из полей film_id, actor_id и role_id